# Why is it not possible to upload images via link anymore?

Tags: support, images

[image]

Am I missing something or is was it a conscious decision to remove that feature in this interface?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's still possible, but hidden.

From [No option to upload image from URL anymore](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/317591),

> We currently don't have an explicit entry point for this, but you can paste an image link when the uploader UX is showing.
>
> We will be updating the experience to add an explicit link to upload via URL. That is coming soon.

However, this is still an issue with touch devices as reported on [How to insert image by link using touch devices?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/317954).

> There's currently no way to do that directly, which is the biggest problem with the "invisible" paste target.
>
> Right now your best workaround is to download the image with a browser and then upload it via the file picker.
>
> Fortunately we have a design tweak in the works that will make this possible again.